# Smart folder using "or" search?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, finder-tag, smart-folders

Is there a way to create a macOS smart folder which uses an "or" search? E.g. find all files which have tags "A" or "B"? It seems that smart folders allow only to search using an "and" command.

Answer (score 14):

Yes there is. 
If you press the OPTION button while composing the query in the finder window, the "+" button changes into a "..." button, that exposes the interface that allows for testing "All | Any | None" of the subsequent conditions.

Comment: Wanted to note that this OPTION behaviour persists in Reminders as well.